# Swift swipe gesture recogniser errors

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm building a iOS Swift (Sprite kit) game. I'm using swipes to move the player. While testing I've found out that everything works just fine on most devices. However, a few devices do not recognise the swipe. Needless to say, the game doesn't work without the swipes. It's very odd that it works on almost all devices but a few.

My code is below. (Note: It's cleaned up to show only the code relevant for this case)

**Edit**

The app is currently being tested on actual devices. All devices run the latest iOS software. Mostly iPhone 5, a few 6 and 5S. Error occurs on iPhone 5S.

**Am I missing something? If not, what else could I try?**

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    addSwipes()
}

func addSwipes() {

        let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
        swipeRight.direction = .Right
        view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
        swipeLeft.direction = .Left
        view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
}

func swipedRight(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    // Do code here
}

func swipedLeft(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    // Do code here        
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on what devices you are running into issues with? Is it on the actual device or is it in the simulator?

Comment: @timgcarlson See edit.

Comment: Are there any runtime warnings during application startup on 5s? I understand that this is an incredible option but maybe on the device for some reason SEL type from ObjC does not maps to the Selector type and swipedRight and swipeLeft dont call. And to fix this need to add @objc before method's declaration.